# What is the "Early Transmit Interrupt" in the STM32F4x Ethernet MAC DMA status register?

Tags: networking, embedded, stm32, ethernet, freertos

My FreeRTOS **Ethernet driver** pop-out a lot of "*Early transmit interrupt*" on my STM32F4x board. I did not find any explanation about this "abnormal" interrupt despite :

> Indicates that the packet to be transmitted was fully transferred into
>   the FIFO

So what's the problem ? It looks like everything is going well.
What does it mean ?

Datasheet **STM32F401xx** :

> Ethernet DMA status register (**ETH_DMASR**) *p.1228*
>
> - BIT 10 **ETS**: Early transmit status
>
> Ethernet DMA interrupt enable register (**ETH_DMAIER**) *p.1233*
>
> - BIT 10 **ETIE**: Early transmit interrupt enable

Answer (score 2):

The Datasheet of *PCI 10/100 Ethernet controller STE10/100A* gives a good description of what's going on.

[image: Transmit early interrupt scheme]

As shown on this scheme, there is two possible interrupts on TX :

1. **Normal Transmit Interrupt** (TS : bit 0) (summarized among "normal interrupts").

> This bit indicates that frame transmission is finished.

2. **Early Transmit Interrupt** (ETS : bit 10) (summarized among "abnormal interrupts").

> This bit indicates that the frame to be transmitted was fully transferred to the Transmit FIFO. This is the first step in the transmit process.

---

- The second one (ETS) just let the possibility for the Host to detect
  and prevent under-run on TX. It is quite a blurry naming for a
  simple trick.
- Furthermore, this case can occur in "normal" situations when there is only one frame < 1500 bytes to be transmitted.